# How do you add touch outlets to custom UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

I've created the following custom UIVIew:

```
//
//  YearSelectorSegControl.swift
//  OurDailyStrength iOS
//
//  Created by Rob Avery on 8/28/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Rob Avery. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class YearSelectorSegControl: UIView {

    var buttons = [UIButton]()
    var selector: UIView!
    var sv: UIStackView!

    var currentPosition: Int = 0

    @IBInspectable
    var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var textColor: UIColor = .lightGray {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var textBackground: UIColor = .clear {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }

    func updateView() {
        // ... code here ...
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        layer.cornerRadius = 0
    }
}
```

When I go to the Interface Builder, and try and connect this UIView to the controller, the only thing allowed is an outlet. I want to be able to connect this custom UIView to a function when it's touched. How do I do that?

Comment: why you don't try this on storyboard?

Comment: @Thili77 that's what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subclass UIControl instead of UIView

```
@IBDesignable
class YearSelectorSegControl: UIControl {
   ...
}
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: UIControl subclass UIView, but xcode allow to connect @IBActions to it.

Comment: It may be a problem with something I'm doing. I've tried adding a gesture programmatically and doing this. The function never gets called.

Comment: I realized that I had subviews with userInteractiveEnabled which means the subviews were getting all the events. Once I disabled userInteractiveEnabled for all the subviews, that solved it.

Comment: The UIControl approach is much better if the connection you want to establish is one of the defaults one (ie, onTouchDownOutside, onTouchUpInside, etc). In the case you add a gesture recognizer, you have to manage the touch down and up, and all the others variables

Answer (score -1):

Using storyboard,

1. Change the class of `UIView` on identity inspector as `UIButton`
2. Now you can set action connection to that `UIView` as `UIButton`

[image]

See below code

```
@IBAction func clickView(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //perform your actions in here

}
```

Comment: but then you can't subclass UIView